# ffmpeg recording video from live stream closed if connention intrupt

Tags: bash, ubuntu, video, ffmpeg, stream

I am facing a issue with FFMPEG stream. I am trying to record my live running stream to File_Name.ts file.  Its working fine with following code

```
ffmpeg -i "http://clientportal.link:8080/live/tmalik/Tanveer/9026.m3u8" -c copy abc.ts -y
```

But actual issue is that my input stream is not much stable and its stop after average 1 hour for 4-6 sec.

Now is there any way that i can re-connect automatically if i got my stream back from Link(given above in code as input).

Important thing is m working on UBUNTU machine. So if there is any bash file that would be grate.

Comment: if you are missing critical video until you get this fixed, you can use a stop-gap solution like put your cmd in an "infinite" loop, i.e. `while true ; do ffmpeg .... ; done` and this will restart ffmpeg each time it stops. Maybe you want to add a date/time stamp to the file name so you can assemble them later with some software. (I know such things exist, but can't tell you what to use). Use `-c copy abc.$(/bin/date +%Y%m%d.%H%M%S).ts ...` to add a new date-stamp to each file as it is created. Good luck.

Comment: thanks for quick reply. I am not gud with bash can you help me with this.

Comment: I will help you a little, but I don't want to turn into technical support. Busy now, will post a more complete version of above a little later. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make a bash script like

```
#!/bin/bash
# this script will run until someone kills it
echo PID="$PID"
while true ; do
    startDateTime=$(/bin/date +%Y-%m-%d.%H%M)
    echo "starting ffmpeg at ${startDateTime}"
    ffmpeg -i "http://clientportal.link:8080/live/tmalik/Tanveer/9026.m3u8" -c copy abc."${startDateTime}".ts -y
    # sleep 0.5
done
```

Save this to a file (don't use a Windows Editor to save it, just a plain text editor).

Now mark the file as executable (so it will run as a script), with

```
chmod +x ffmpegRestarter.sh
```

Run it from your terminal command line as

```
nohup /path/to/ffmpegRestarter.sh > /tmp/ffmpegRestarter.log.${startDateTime}.$$ 2>&1 &
```

(changing of course, `/path/to` to the proper path to the script.)

You can now do other things in your terminal session, OR you can start up another terminal session, just for monitoring,  and you can look at the end of the /tmp/${logName}.log file to see how things are going by using

```
tail -f /tmp/ffmpegRestarter.log."${startDateTime}".*
```

You use `Ctrl-C` to stop watching the file.

You can quit your terminal altogether and return later to look at that file.

You'll also want to monitor what files are being created, so use these two commands

```
/bin/ls -l /path/to/abc.* | tail -5
/bin/ls -l /tmp/ffmpegRestarter.log.* | tail -5
```

You can change `-5` to any number you want, and it will show you the last `N` files of each type.

If you think there is a problem and want to kill the script, use

```
pid=$(grep '[P]ID=' /tmp/ffmpegRestarter.log.YYYY-MM-DD.HHMM.$$)
pid=${pid#PID=}
ps -ef | grep "$pid"   # this line to confirm that the job is still running
# will return something like
# userX    1088  1029  0 16:31 ?        00:00:00 /path/to/ffmpegRestarter.sh
kill $pid

#worst case, use
kill -9 $pid
# dont get in a habit of using `-9` on kill, bad things can happen! ;-)
```

I've left a couple of minor errors in this, so you'll have to think about what is going on and *what is missing* ;-) ...

---

Per your query "run another program after 30 seconds", all you need is

```
nohup /path/to/ffmpegRestarter.sh > /tmp/ffmpegRestarter.log.${startDateTime}.$$ 2>&1 &
sleep 30
anotherProgram
```

IHTH.

Comment: thanks for this script. its working fine and perfect. just one last thing i need to now. Can i start another process with bash file after 30 sec ?

Comment: @FarhanShahid :http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/160242 :-) . Good luck.

Comment: I try this but no luck. #!/bin/bash
# this script will run until someone kills it
echo PID="$PID"
while true ; do
    startDateTime=$(/bin/date +%Y-%m-%d.%H%M)
    echo "starting ffmpeg at ${startDateTime}"
    ffmpeg -i "http://clientportal.link:8080/live/tmalik/Tanveer/9026.m3u8" -c copy /home/tanveer/channels_ts/abc.ts -y
    sleep 10
echo "Starting vlc for ABC"
vlc -vvv "file:///home/tanveer/channels_ts/abc.ts" --sout '#std{access=http,mux=ts,dst=:55665/ABC_NEW}'
done

Comment: Remeber what I said about technical support ? I have answered your original Q. Please accept that answer and then post a new question. I will help you if I can. Good luck.

Comment: thats the last thing i want to do with this code. just have to play VLC as well after 10 sec or 30 sec in while loop

Comment: Your use-case become less clear all the time. And I'n Not sure what you mean by "thats the last thing I want to do with this code". I don't want to   play20 Qs in comments. Post a new question and I will help you if I can. Good luck.

Comment: See revised last comment ;-)